# Fetch data from PS_JOB AND PS-COMPENSATION and generate multiple reports in PDF and Excel

Tags: sqr

I want to fetch data from PS_JOB AND PS-COMPENSATION and need to generate multiple reports in pdf and excel. The condition the employees whose annual salary is greater than 35000 need to be in excel and less than should be in PDF.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Do you have a specific issue you are having trouble with?

Comment: I want that sqr code how to fetch the details and generate a report in excel and pdf

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, most people here will not write entire programs for you on request. Please provide what you have tried so far and explain what didn't work so we can help fix your code.